# TSQL Transpose Single Column Into Row

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have one column with row count from 0 to 3

```
test1
test2
test3
```

I need to convert it into row with **three** columns

```
test1 | test2 | test3
```

Or

```
test1
test2
```

Goes to

```
test1 | test2 | NULL
```

I **can not** use PIVOT

I **can not** use LOOPS

Can it be done with single query? **Hardcode is acceptable!**

Comment: Is there any id on your table? Or something else to group rows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is quite vague, but maybe you need something like this:

```
select
  max(case when RN = 1 then value end),
  max(case when RN = 2 then value end),
  max(case when RN = 3 then value end)
from
(
  select value, row_number() over (order by value) as RN
  from yourtable
) x
```

This will take up to 3 values from column called value and order then alphabetically into 3 columns.

Answer (score 0):

```
;WITH example AS (
SELECT *
FROM (VALUES
(1, 'test1'),
(1, 'test2'),
(1, 'test3'),
(2, 'test1'),
(2, 'test2')
) as t(id, string)
)

SELECT top 1 with ties  e1.string,
                        e2.string,
                        e3.string
FROM example e1
left join example e2
    on e1.id = e2.id and e1.string != e2.string
left join example e3
    on e1.id = e3.id and e1.string != e3.string and e2.string != e3.string
ORDER BY ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY e1.id ORDER By e1.string,e2.string,e3.string)
```

Output:

```
string  string  string
test1   test2   test3
test1   test2   NULL
```

But if there are values with various lens in string there might be another order in rows.

Answer (score 0):

```
create table #t (mycolumn varchar(10))

insert into #t values ('test1'),('test2'),('test3'),(NULL)
declare @r varchar(max)

select @r = COALESCE(@r + ' | ', '') + COALESCE(mycolumn,'NULL')
from #t

select @r

    input:
    mycolumn
    --------
    test1
    test2
    test3
    NULL

    output:
    test1 | test2 | test3 | NULL
```